# Alter nvarchar column type to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN columnWithDate datetime;
```

columnWithDate is a type of nvarchar(255), data are in `2018.06.19.` form. I've checked all distinct values and there are one row with NULL value in columnWithDate.

I get the following error runninf the alter command:

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well the value "2018.06.19." is not a valid datetime string. It has a trailing period which is an issue. But the real issue is that most likely you have some value that is not an actual date like February 30 or June 31.

Comment: @SeanLange  "2018.06.19" will indeed convert to datetime ..  Select try_convert(datetime,'2018.06.19')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti in the OP it has a period AFTER 19 "2018.06.19."

Comment: @SeanLange Did I?  Or is that just bad highlighting?

Comment: On second look, I agree trailing period

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I can only assume that the value they highlighted is the value in the table. Yet another reason why clear sample data is so important. Using their highlighted data would in fact result in the error message they posted.

Comment: I do have a period trailing after the dates, @SeanLange sees it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first change your values to a unambiguous format and then change the datatype. For the value you have that would be simply removing the `.`, as that produces the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourDateColumn = REPLACE(YourDateColumn,'.','');

ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDateColumn datetime; --Should this not be a date?
```

As I comment though, `date` would likely be a better choice here, as you have no time portion in your value(s).

Comment: Plus 1 for seeing the trailing period.  This works provided there are no milliseconds in the datetime string.

Comment: In fairness, I assume that the OP only has a date, and not even a hour portion for the time @JohnCappelletti (hence the added comment about using `date` instead of `datetime`). Of course, I only had 1 sample to base my assumptions on. :/

Comment: Thank you for a complete suggestion with the trailing period thing. You are right, I don't have time portion in that column. I have another column where I do have those time portions, only that every instance is in a ```2018-06-19 00:00:00.000``` format with no real time portion values. Can I convert this datetime to date as well?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the extra dot(.) after the date is the culprit. In your example  `2018.06.19.`

This below snippet giving me the same error

```
DECLARE @DATE NVARCHAR(255)= N'2018.06.19.'

SELECT CAST(@DATE AS datetime)
```

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 The conversion of a nvarchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

So just remove the dot from the nvarchar field befor Alter.

Answer (score 1):

The value is not correct somewhere in the column.  I would suggest finding it:

```
select columnWithDate
from table_name
where try_convert(datetime, columnWithDate) is null and
      columnWithDate is not null;
```

If you want to remove incorrect dates, then `update` first:

```
update table_name
    set columnWithDate = try_convert(datetime, columnWithDate);
```

This converts the value back to a string, but the string should be convertible on your system right back to a `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! As others have pointed out my column had a trailing period at the end of the dates. That was the problem.